# Joining multiple different update queries into single query - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Apologies if something similar has been asked before, currently I run 3 different update queries in order to get the desired result. The Queries are as follows,

```
UPDATE users SET enabled = false where username in (SELECT username
FROM users WHERE enabled = true AND lastaccess != 0 AND lastaccess
< (EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (86400*200))*1000 AND
username NOT LIKE ('admintest%'));
```

Once this query runs (disabling all users who haven't accessed the system in a certain period), then I run the following 2 Queries on the whole table,

```
update users set weeklypopupuse = 0;

update users set monthlypopupuse = 0;
```

These 2 queries then reset the weekly and monthly use to 0.

Now this works perfectly fine as per the requirements, however is there a more elegant way of writing all these 3 queries into a single query which gives the same result.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have two different tables, `users` and `hanetusers`?

Comment: My mistake @GordonLinoff, actually it's only one table 'users' ... I've updated the above queries ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**
after OP gave full structure, refactored to:

```
update users 
set 
  weeklypopupuse = 0
, monthlypopupuse = 0
, enabled = case 
  when 
  enabled = true 
      AND lastaccess != 0 
      AND lastaccess < (EXTRACT('epoch' FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - (86400*200))*1000 
      AND username NOT LIKE ('admintest%') 
   then false 
   end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - I'll take a look at what you suggested ... just one thing, it was my fault, there is only one table called 'users' ... I accidently typed in 'hanetusers' ... it's supposed to be 'users' as well

Comment: well - you have different `where` conditions, so can't group three to one - only two to one

Comment: Can you explain why we had to use "with u as ( ... ) " and why can't we use without it?

Comment: you surely can, CTE is just neater here

Comment: Brilliant! Understood, works like a charm! I've updated the query a little more, using two CTEs, taking value from one and using it in another ... works great ... Thanks

Comment: please don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163237/discussion-between-rac3b3nn0n-and-vao-tsun).